# BIRT viewer - local csv

Tags: tomcat, birt

I'm sure some people will easily solve this:)
I have a report in BIRT that access a local CSV file.
I use an old version of BIRT viewer and the report runs fine.

I want to upgrade to the latest version (actually 4.2.2 as 4.6.0 has issues)

That report works in the designer (my PC and the server) but not in BIRT viewer.

I'm guessing it's a tomcat configuration issue.
I'm using tomcat 9.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: save the old report with the new designer. So the version number in the report is updated. Than try to open it with the viewer.

Comment: I tried that.I also tried to save the CSV in the same folder as the report (and updated the report).. Didn't work

Comment: What's your error?